# Cup full of espresso shots?

Tags: espresso, coffee-culture

Is it considered rude or faux pas to take a full cup of espresso shots at a company break-room? Does it change if it's decaf espresso?

I've only really gone for it after a greasy/oily lunch but for some reason it makes me feel like I have something to hide or something because I'm using 3 packets for my drink.

Comment: I really don't like this question since this is more about etiquette in the workroom

Comment: I'm sorry: this was the only stack exchange community that I thought would be relevant.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be moved to the workplace stackexchange site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the culture at your office. I work with other developers and coffee is considered to be an essential work tool equal in importance to computers and chairs.

Having three "packets" of espresso at one time, or over 10 minutes, would not be noticed.

Again, the answer to this question depends on the culture at your place of work.

Comment: Can't say how many espresso packets I've taken, but when I double brew a pot of coffee and pour half the pot into my trucker mug the only comment I might get is 'rough day?' LOL.  Mayo is correct, definitely up to office culture.  That being said, at my previous development job, there was a tip jar, and it was faux pa to not throw some cash in every once in a while just so that we could help fund buying quality coffee.